# Search all Files in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I do not see an option to search for a term in all code files in WebStorm 6.0.  Does anyone know how to search all files for certain keyword/text?

Answer (score 43):

`Edit` | `Find` | `Find in Path` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the default keymap).

- [Finding and Replacing Text in Project](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)

Comment: I know I'll probably get burned for this comment, but where did you learn this stuff? I'm just starting out web dev, and I need a good "how to find XYZ information" schema.

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange he linked to the official documentation... and he works for the company who developed this product. :)

Comment: I am looking for a response for a definition schema from +CrazyCoder. I don't want to get confirmation bias, so I am making the request as is.

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange `Help` | `Find Action`, `Help` | `Default Keymap Reference`

Comment: Pretty sure that it then searches in the path that you have selected in the Project tab.

Answer (score 12):

In Mac, you can do it by `cmd`+`shift`+`F` shortcut.

Comment: The "Navigate" menu item holds alot of "find" related options. This is a useful link for Webstorm 10 - https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

You can also find the other shortcuts in [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html).