# Search for files in WebStorm - not a term in all files in the project

Tags: ide, webstorm

In the Project View, when there are so many files, it's time consuming to collapse and expand and navigate through all the items. How can I search for files in the project?

I have [searched for it online many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941196/search-all-files-in-webstorm), but most of them explain the `Ctrl + Shift + F` which actually searches for *terms in all the files in the current project*, this is convenient but yet it's not what I'm looking for.

I want to search for actual files in the project and *not* terms within them. I don't know if this feature is available by default in WebStorm (which so obviously should, and don't know why many IDEs don't have it), but please mention any plugins that emulate this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a file by name, try using **Navigate > File** or **Search Everywhere** (`Shift+Shift`, or the magnifying glass icon on the main toolbar). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/searching-everywhere.html#ws_search_files

Note also that the **Project** tool window has a quick search - just focus it and start entering the file name

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply. just what I wanted. But, can you tell me where does the project tool window have a quick search? I found the one in the main toolbar, but, there's non in the project tool window

Comment: @juztcode Just focus the toolwindow/files and start typing.